# What is the meaning of the asterisk before an array key name in print_r

Tags: php

When using `print_r($myArray, true)` for one of my arrays I get:

```
Array
(
     [id] => 14
     [name] => My Name
     [*createdAt] => Carbon\Carbon Object
         (
             [date] => 2020-03-18 10:00:26.000000
             [timezone_type] => 3
             [timezone] => UTC
         )

     [*updatedAt] => Carbon\Carbon Object
         (
             [date] => 2020-08-26 10:10:10.000000
             [timezone_type] => 3
             [timezone] => UTC
         )
)
```

What is the meaning of the asterisk in `[*createdAt]` and `[*updatedAt]`?

Also, I cannot access these fields. How can I access them?

Comment: Do you cast object to array?

Comment: Tried accessing them without the *?

Comment: Could be worth checking [PHP doesn't find array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303092/php-doesnt-find-array-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk indicates an Object. And it is protected. This is the reason why you can't access them.